# I am not able to replace duplicate numbers with a character "a"

Tags: c++

```
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n-1; j++) {
        if (arr[i]==arr[j]) {
            arr[j]=a;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I can't replace duplicate number with a character "a"

Comment: Why is not working? What result do you get instead?

Comment: @Usman Qamar Do you mean 'a'?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes

Comment: @Simon it replace duplicate with 0

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean the following

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) 
    {
        if ( arr[i] == arr[j] ) arr[j] = 'a';
    }
}
```

or more efficiently

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    if ( a[i] != 'a' )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) 
        {
            if ( arr[i] == arr[j] ) arr[j] = 'a';
        }
    }
}
```